# Java web service error

Tags: java, web-services, semantic-web, jena

I got this error 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model' when I run my java web service which implement a jena framework function such as OWL reading function. But it worked as a standalone java application and read the owl file correctly. But when I host it as web service and execute the read method in a .net client or eclipse web service client, it gives this error.

any help would really appreciated.

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that suggests you've not got all the jar files you need at execution time. In particular, find the jar file that contains that class, and make sure it's in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory appropriately (or however else you specify dependencies in your web service contain).